# OpenStreetMap Nominatim schema: neighborhood, suburb, city, state_district, etc

Tags: gps, maps, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am trying out the OpenStreetMap [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) reverse-geocoder RESTFul API.

Is there a definitive explanation of the address schema returned from the API? Some locations have different attributes in the 'addressparts' block.

For example, for [Seattle](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=47.60647&lon=-122.32644&zoom=18&addressdetails=1), Nominatim includes "suburb" and "city" attributes.

```
<reversegeocode timestamp="Tue, 19 Nov 13 01:48:51 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="format=xml&lat=47.60647&lon=-122.32644&zoom=18&addressdetails=1">
  <result place_id="3681763473" osm_type="node" osm_id="2159323135" lat="47.6065166" lon="-122.3262919">
725, 9th Avenue, First Hill, Seattle, King, Washington, 98104, United States of America
</result>
  <addressparts>
    <house_number>725</house_number>
    <road>9th Avenue</road>
    <suburb>First Hill</suburb>
    <city>Seattle</city>
    <county>King</county>
    <state>Washington</state>
    <postcode>98104</postcode>
    <country>United States of America</country>
    <country_code>us</country_code>
  </addressparts>
</reversegeocode>
```

However, for [New York City](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=40.71812&lon=-73.98298&zoom=18&addressdetails=1), it returns "neighborhood" and "state_district" attributes.

```
<reversegeocode timestamp="Tue, 19 Nov 13 01:50:16 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="format=xml&lat=40.71812&lon=-73.98298&zoom=18&addressdetails=1">
  <result place_id="5989088711" osm_type="node" osm_id="2273010097" ref="N.Y. Grill & Deli" lat="40.7184546" lon="-73.9828337">
N.Y. Grill & Deli, 208, Rivington Street, Lower East Side, New York City, New York, 10002, United States of America
</result>
  <addressparts>
    <address29>N.Y. Grill & Deli</address29>
    <house_number>208</house_number>
    <road>Rivington Street</road>
    <neighbourhood>Lower East Side</neighbourhood>
    <state_district>New York City</state_district>
    <county>New York</county>
    <state>New York</state>
    <postcode>10002</postcode>
    <country>United States of America</country>
    <country_code>us</country_code>
  </addressparts>
</reversegeocode>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is currently not very much documentation except for the [Nominatim wiki page and subpages](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and the source code. But these categories are generated with the help of the `admin_level` key found on [boundary=administration](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative) relations and via the [`place`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aplace) and [`addr`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aaddr) tags. Each wiki page contains some information about possible values for the corresponding keys.

Comment: Source code's a good place to look – [functions.sql](https://git.openstreetmap.org/nominatim.git/blob/HEAD:/sql/functions.sql) has most of the attributes that will show up